# Creating dynamic objects with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a new Javascript object from attributes pulled from the DOM using jQuery.
The info I'm trying to pull is the data-* from this:

```
    <button type='button' class='pickup' data-name="apple" data-weight='1' data-color='red'>food</button>
```

So I want to get data-name and data-weight and put them into a new (or existing if I have to) object. Here's where I'm having problems. I want the object to look like this:

```
    MyObject = {
                food:  {
                        weight: 1,
                        color: 'red'
                       }
                }
```

I've been trying to create a new object like this through a "for(var i in MyObject)" loop, but when it comes down to adding the attributes and values to MyObject{} I can't figure out how to make it work.

Any ideas or suggestions?

---

The answers below worked perfectly! Thank you!
How if I wanted to dynamically create:

```
    MyObject.food = {}
```

from a variable, like this:

```
    var Name = "meal";
    MyObject.Name = {} // creates MyObject.meal = {};
```

How would I do that? I thought MyObject[Name] = {} would work but it didnt seem to for me. Maybe I typed it wrong? :S

Answer (score 4):

If you don't know what the attributes will be, you could loop the `.attributes` object.

```
var attrs = $('.pickup')[0].attributes;  // grab the attributes of the element

var MyObject = {  // create the object
    food: {}
};

  // loop the attributes, and add the data- attributes to the object
$.each(attrs, function(_, v) {
    if (v.name.indexOf('data-') !== -1)
        MyObject.food[v.name.replace('data-', '')] = v.value;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5m7KF/

---

In HTML5 compliant browsers, you could use the `.dataset` property of the element to get the `data-` attributes.

```
var data = $('.pickup')[0].dataset;  

var MyObject = {  
    food: {}
};

$.each(data, function(k, v) {
    MyObject.food[k] = v;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5m7KF/1/

Comment: Tidy! Note for Kabe - the key is that MyObject's hierarchy is created in advance. If you just have MyObject = {} you cannot arbitrarily add MyObject.food[value] = someValue. The food object within MyObject needs to be there in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
var FinalObject= {}
$('.filter-products select').each(function() {
   var property= $(this).attr('id');
   var value = $(this).val();
   FinalObject[property] = value;
});

console.log(FinalObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(".pickup").data("name")` will fetch you "apple", etc.

Complete-ish example off the top of my head.

```
$(".pickup").click(function(){
    MyObject = {
        food:  {
            weight: $(this).data("weight"),
            color: $(this).data("color")
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: if not, `document.querySelector(".pickup").getAttribute("data-name")` will do the same thing.

Comment: @JKing's comment is with regard to something I said before my edit. I asked if it was ok for him to use jQuery. But, then I noticed he was already using it. Keep your comment there, though. I didn't know about that. +1'd

Comment: Thanks for that! With your edit removing the context of what I was referring to, I do sound a bit insane. Also, it's funny, I can't tell you how many times I've seen someone just using the "query" part of jQuery, and blown their minds with document.querySelector/querySelectorAll. I don't mean to dissuade folks from jQuery, though, there is a lot of great/useful stuff that it can do! But, you can do a lot more with vanilla JavaScript these days than some folks would have you believe...

Comment: @JKing, you shouldn't really use `document.querySelector`, because it is **much** slower than jQuery and `document.getElementById/Classname`.

Comment: @Derek Thanks, always appreciate performance tips! But, I found it a bit odd that a library would beat out a built-in method, and I was curious to see just how much faster it was. So, I Googled it, and stumbled across this: http://jsperf.com/select-vs-natives-vs-jquery/10 - Maybe I'm missing something, but it looks to me like querySelector and jQuery are about tied (with querySelector beating it just barely), though both are put to shame by the native getElementById/ClassName (which I do try to use as much as possible, except when showing "light" jQuery users that they don't really need it...)

Comment: Aaaand, now I'm looking again and seeing other tests that have jQuery beating out querySelector... Sorry. Guess it's worth performance testing on a case-by-case basis. Good thing the WebKit inspector makes it so easy!

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery like this

```
var d = $(".pickup").data();
```

"d" is a Object with attributes of $('.pickup') start with 'data-',then you  can use it
hope it can help you!